# Specify range of graph using NumPy linspace

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot some graphs, but having trouble with the range of my graph. I need to plot from x = 50 to x = 200, but the plot doesn't give the range I intended.

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nc = 2.8 * 10**19 #Effective density of states in conduction band
Nd = 10**16 #Effective density of states in valence band
Ei = 0.045 #ionization energy of Boron
k = 8.62 * 10 **(-5) #Boltzmann's constant


x = np.linspace(50, 200)
y = 1 / (1 + ( Nc * np.exp(-Ei/( k * x )) ) / (2 * Nd ) )

plt.plot(y, 'r')
plt.xlabel("T in kelvin")
plt.ylabel("Ratio")
plt.title("Exercise 4.3")

plt.show()
```

Here is the plot I got.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide `x` values for the `plot` function:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
```

Without this, it presumes the x-values are incremented by 1 starting at 0, which is why your x scale was from 0 to 50.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should upvote and/or accept this answer.